How to bake material with image to one texture properly?
I made a knight model. I placed a png image of a lion on the shield. Other materials are just colors. I need to bake all the materials into one texture for the game engine. But when I did that, the baked texture only contained part of the lion.
I think the problem is that the lion image is not scaled for UV map baking. But I don't understand how to fix it.
So the baking result and problems looks like this:

The lion material consists of a png image and a steel material background (SteelNodeGroup). Mapping was used to position the lion on one side only.

The default uv map and shield as I want:

The uv map for baking all knight to one texture:

The same uv map but on lion image:

I try to put uv map nodes to material, but result is shield without lion:


Try this: Select one vertex of the shield in the UV editor, hover over it and hit 'L'. Now you can rotate it using R-90, scale it with 'S' and move it to the correct position with 'G' just like normal modelling.

This won't fix the current issue, but the Mapping node in that shader is all zeroed, so it is doing nothing.

You have correctly created two different UV maps: one for placing the lion on the shield, and one for baking the whole character: in my example they are called respectively "UVMap_Shield_Lion" and "UVMap_Character_and_Shield".
During the baking process you have to tell explicity which UV Map every image should use: if you don't, the default UV map will be always used (the one which has the camera icon enabled in the UV maps list).
Remember to copy and paste the image node in which you want to bake, with its UV map selector node, in every material involved in the baking process, leaving the image node unconnected and selected.

EDIT:
In your file there was some mess in the materials: there was more than one material output nodes (one was contained in the "Steel" node group) and the lion image was directly connected as shader, resulting in an emission component, that didn't get baked in the diffuse pass.
In the steel material, as metallic is 1.0, no diffuse component is present, so if you want a diffuse color to be baked you have to temporarily turn off the metalness slider.
This is the result after cleaning up the materials:


Hi. I try this but there is no lion on the shield in the baked texture. Add a screenshot to the end of my question.

It should work. Did you bake with Type: "Diffuse" and Influence: "Color" (no Direct, nor Indirect)? All "Baking" image texure nodes have to be selected during baking. If the problem persist use the menu File > External Data > Pack Resources, then upload the file here.

Didn't work. Thanks for your help.
Link to blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-uHMjRO4_MJF6HWwVRLuf42IIVjpUwjm/view?usp=drive_link

An access permission is asked for downloading the file.

Update permissions. Sorry.

I updated my answer, check your normals also, because some of them have to be inverted.

I updated the materials as in the screenshot, but it didn't work. Now there is a side effect: the baking process overwrites not only the baking texture, but also the lion texture. After that, I lose the lion.
Update file on drive.
I check normals. They are bad on knees but on shield all looks good.
What version of blender do you use? I use 3.6.

Baking Image texture nodes have to be selected on both materials when hitting Bake button: this is the way you tell blender which image to overwrite, probably you had Lion image texture node selected instead. I'm using 4.2 but baking should be the same in 3.6. Normals on the shield are ok.

You are great! I didn't know about the need to select nodes. Now everything works.
But I have a question. What if I have a very complex mesh with hundends materials? Do I have to go through the entire hundred to bake? Are there easier ways?

In theese tasks vanilla Blender is weak. The professional way is to write a little Python script to automate the task

Thank you very much!
