I want to bake a UV texture that the UV is out of bounds
So I have a model where the UV map exceeds the bounds of the image, the reason why is because i need it to repeat around in a circle.

But when baked it looks like this

When pluging the baked texture it doesn't work. How would I make it so I can tile in a circle and bake it out because it is for a game engine as a texture. I already tried just uv unwrapping it normally and changing the image node setting from flat to sphere but I couldn't get it to work properly with size and stretching since I also have another one with many bricks.


You have to create an additional UV Map that fits the baking and export needs, see this related question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/323354/how-to-bake-material-with-image-to-one-texture-properly/323369?noredirect=1#comment564271_323369

Why do you have to bake it in the first place? Does your game engine not allow UVs outside the 0-1 space or something? The UVs I see in the first image are totally fine for an environment asset like this.

Can you move the UV map slightly so that the faces perfectly land on the map, and then move faces that are out of bounds to be in-bounds on the wrapped location?

I'm so confused. You baked it. It looks fine. And then when you use the baked texture the UVs change? Can you share your blend file?
